# Create raster layer from points with PostGIS

Tags: postgis, postgresql, rasterization

I'm pretty new to this part of GIS; I have a layer of points that represent cell phone towers; with a given distance to simulate coverage, how can I transform that represented coverage into a raster? like this:

[image]

Comment: do you need any form of alignment with another raster? do you want a defined ground-to-pixel ratio (ground resolution) or simply a defined image size? do you want the result saved to DB or as raster data (png, jpeg, tiff)? [this](http://geospatialelucubrations.blogspot.com/2014/05/a-guide-to-rasterization-of-vector.html?m=1) is a good introduction to PostGIS' raster capabilities (the example might not be the best way for your case, though).

Comment: if you don't specifically need to have a (tiled) raster in-DB e.g. for serving tiles, have an external application/framework use the results or run more complex analysis with in-DB vector geometries on the results, consider importing buffers of your points into QGIS and do the rasterization there. you'll save yourself unnecessary hussle...